# If $f_1(n) ∈ O(g_1(n))$ and $f_2(n) ∈ O(g_2(n))$ show that $f_1(n)+f_2(n) ∈ O(max(g_1(n), g_2(n)))$

Tags: computer-science

If $f_1(n) ∈ O(g_1(n))$ and $f_2(n) ∈ O(g_2(n))$ show that $f_1(n)+f_2(n) ∈ O(max(g_1(n), g_2(n)))$

I know that: $$f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) \iff \exists\ C >0, n_0\geq0\ | f(n) \leq C *g(n)\ \forall\ n\geq{n_0}$$

How to get proof with this information?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?